# Change time in DateFormat on Android

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

I have date and time extracted from JSON in following format

```
2013-01-16T13:43:11
```

I need to convert it to local time of Pakistan and add 5 hours to that time so the result is like:

```
06:43
```

How I can achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `"2013-01-16T13:43:11"` is in GMT

```
String s = "2013-01-16T13:43:11";
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
Date date = df.parse(s);
date = new Date(date.getTime() + 5 * 3600 * 1000);
String time = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(date);
```

`time` will be in your local timezone, so if you are in Pakistan it will be OK

Comment: it is GMT need to convert it to Paksitan Time Also

Comment: OK, fixed answer, check it

Answer (score 1):

You can use SimpleDateFormat as below:

```
String strDate = null;
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "hh:mm");
strDate = dateFormatter.format(yourDate);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Android also includes Apache's DateUtils which already has parsers for common "HTTP" date formats, which are also used a lot in JSON. And, it has its own DateUtils in the text.format package for common formatting cases (and it will format for whatever the device locale/lang is). Shreya's answer is correct, but the utils may come in handy too (just search the Android docs for DateUtils for info on both).

Answer (score 1):

java dateFormat is not threadsafe, use joda time lib instead:

[Joda time lib download](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)

you can use withZone method to change time with specific Timezone

```
DateTime userTime1 = new DateTime();
            DateTime eventRecordTime = new DateTime();
            userTime1 = DateTime.parse("2012-07-05T21:45:00+02:00");
            eventRecordTime = DateTime.parse((String) jo.get("start_time"));
            DateTimeZone dtz = userTime1.getZone();
            System.out.println(eventRecordTime.withZone(dtz).toString());
```